# Binding a control completely, not only a property

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 application with an User Control.

This user control has a border, and I want to create a DependencyProperty to access this border:

```
public partial class CustomOptionButton : UserControl
{

    public Border OuterBorder
    {
        get
        {
            return (Border)GetValue(OuterBorderProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(OuterBorderProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public readonly DependencyProperty OuterBorderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("OuterBorder", typeof(Border), typeof(CustomOptionButton), null);
```

But I don't know how I can bind this property in XAML.

When I have bind a TextBlock.Text, I did this on XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="CustomText" Text="{Binding ButtonText, ElementName=userControl}" />
```

But, **How can I do the same with the entire Border?**

```
<Border x:Name="OutBorder" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" Margin="0">
```

I will need to change the `BorderBrush` and the `BorderThickness` (and maybe another properties), so I have thought that I could have only one property instead of three or four.

Comment: You might be better off telling us the why you need the border. As there might be a better approach to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well, when you have to access some properties you may need it to change it, don't you? I have updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to create for each type of *separate* property, because to use one property `Border` need to create a separate Control like this:

```
public сlass MyBorderControl : Border
{
    // Your implementation of Control
}
```

If you want to create a property that could be used for any `Control`, in WPF has *`attached`* properties:

[`MSDN: Attached properties overview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758282.aspx)

and used like this:

```
<Canvas>
    <Button Canvas.Left="50">Hello</Button>
</Canvas>
```

In this case, `Canvas.Left` attached property used for the `Button` class.